# Differencing with respect to specific value of a column

Tags: r, difference

I have a variable called Depression which has 40 observations and goes from 2004 to 2013 quarterly (e.g. 2004 Q1, 2004 Q2 etc.) I would like to make a new column which differences with respect to the 27th row/observations which corresponds with 2010 Q3 and set that value to 0. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a small example of your data set and show your desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, this would do it:

```
# generate sample data
dat <- data.frame(id=paste0("Obs.",1:40),depression=as.integer(runif(40,0,20)))

# Create new var that calculates difference with 27th observation on depression score
dat$diff <- dat$depression - dat$depression[27]
```